# ReactJs. Horizontal calendar set date

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using library `MomentJS`.
Function `renderDays` renders an array of days.

The problem I am facing is that I need to show only 5 days ahead and 5 days back from the current date.

```
renderDays() {
    const {classes} = this.props;
    const getDaysArrayByMonth = () => {
      let renderAllMonthDays = moment().daysInMonth();
      let listOfDays = [];
      while ( renderAllMonthDays - 17 ) {
        const current = moment().date(renderAllMonthDays);
        listOfDays.push(current);
        renderAllMonthDays--;
      }
      return listOfDays.reverse();
    };
    const days = getDaysArrayByMonth();
    return (
      <div className={classes.daysRow}>
        {_.map(days, (days, index) => (
          <Button className={classes.dayItem} key={index}>
            <div className={classes.dayItemText}>
              <span> {days.format("DD")}</span>
              <span> {days.format("ddd")}</span>
            </div>
          </Button>
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `for()` loop and the `moment.add()` function:

```
let listOfDays = [];
const today = moment();

//start at -5, adding a negative number of days is the same as subtracting
for (let dayDifference = -5; dayDifference <=5; dayDifference++) {

    //make sure we take a copy of the current day, or .add() will change it
    const newDay = moment(today).add(dayDifference, 'days');

    listOfDays.push(newDay);
}
```

If it's important that the array contains only midnights, you can do

```
 const today = moment().startOf('day');
```

instead, but for your purposes it probably won't matter.